# Pandas groupby/apply has different behaviour with int and string types

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```py
   X    Y
0  A   10
1  A    9
2  A    8
3  A    5
4  B  100
5  B   90
6  B   80
7  B   50
```

and two different functions that are very similar

```py
def func1(x):
    if x.iloc[0]['X'] == 'A':
        x['D'] = 1
    else:
        x['D'] = 0
    return x[['X', 'D']]

def func2(x):
    if x.iloc[0]['X'] == 'A':
        x['D'] = 'u'
    else:
        x['D'] = 'v'
    return x[['X', 'D']]
```

Now I can groupby/apply these functions

```py
df.groupby('X').apply(func1)
df.groupby('X').apply(func2)
```

The first line gives me what I want, i.e.

```
   X  D
0  A  1
1  A  1
2  A  1
3  A  1
4  B  0
5  B  0
6  B  0
7  B  0
```

But the second line returns something quite strange

```
   X  D
0  A  u
1  A  u
2  A  u
3  A  u
4  A  u
5  A  u
6  A  u
7  A  u
```

So my questions are:

- Can anybody explain why the behavior of groupby/apply is different when the type changes?
- How can I get something similar with `func2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: Don't really see the point of groupby here, seems you simply want: `df['D'] = np.where(df['X'].eq('A'), 'u', 'v')`

Comment: Thanks @Erfan you're right for this very example but this is not the questions I asked

Comment: You second df columns X only contain A , that is why out put is u only

Comment: @WeNYoBen Both outputs come from the same (given) input. Interested in an explanation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simply that a function applied to a GroupBy should **never** try to change the dataframe it receives. It is implementation dependant whether it is a copy (that can safely be changed but changes will not be seen in original dataframe) or a view. The choice is done by pandas optimizer, and as a user, you should just know that it is forbidden.

The correct way is to force a copy:

```
def func2(x):
    x = x.copy()
    if x.iloc[0]['X'] == 'A':
        x['D'] = 'u'
    else:
        x['D'] = 'v'
    return x[['X', 'D']]
```

After that, `df.groupby('X').apply(func2).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` gives as expected:

```
   X  D
0  A  u
1  A  u
2  A  u
3  A  u
4  B  v
5  B  v
6  B  v
7  B  v
```