# Apply operation to concatenate certain rows in dataframe retuning None

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have some addresses that I would like to clean.

You can see that in column `address1`, we have some entries that are just numbers, where they should be numbers and street names like the first three rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address1':['15 Main Street','10 High Street','5 Other Street',np.nan,'15','12'],
                  'address2':['New York','LA','London','Tokyo','Grove Street','Garden Street']})

print(df)

         address1       address2
0  15 Main Street       New York
1  10 High Street             LA
2  5 Other Street         London
3             NaN          Tokyo
4              15   Grove Street
5              12  Garden Street
```

I'm trying to create a function that will check if `address1` is a number, and if so, concat `address1` and street name from `address2`, then delete `address2`.

My expected output is this. We can see index 4 and 5 now have complete `address1` entries:

```
           address1  address2
0    15 Main Street  New York
1    10 High Street        LA
2    5 Other Street    London
3               NaN     Tokyo
4   15 Grove Street       NaN <---
5  12 Garden Street       NaN <---
```

What I have tried with the .apply() function:

```
def f(x):

    try:
        #if address1 is int
        if isinstance(int(x['address1']), int):

            # create new address using address1 + address 2
            newaddress = str(x['address1']) +' '+ str(x['address2'])

            # delete address2
            x['address2'] = np.nan

            # return newaddress to address1 column
            return newadress

    except:
        pass
```

Applying the function:

```
df['address1'] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

However, the column `address1` is now all `None`.

I've tried a few variations of this function but can't get it to work. Would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may avoid `apply` by using `str.isdigit` to pick exact rows need to modify. Create a mask `m` to identify these rows. Use `agg` on these rows and construct a sub-dataframe for these rows. Finally `append` back to original `df`

```
m = df.address1.astype(str).str.isdigit()
df1 = df[m].agg(' '.join, axis=1).to_frame('address1').assign(address2=np.nan)

Out[179]:
           address1  address2
4   15 Grove Street       NaN
5  12 Garden Street       NaN
```

Finally, `append` it back to `df`

```
df[~m].append(df1)

Out[200]:
           address1  address2
0    15 Main Street  New York
1    10 High Street        LA
2    5 Other Street    London
3               NaN     Tokyo
4   15 Grove Street       NaN
5  12 Garden Street       NaN
```

---

If you still insist to use `apply`, you need modify `f` to return outside of `if` to return non-modify rows together with modified rows

```
def f(x):
    y = x.copy()
    try:
        #if address1 is int
        if isinstance(int(x['address1']), int):

            # create new address using address1 + address 2
            y['address1'] = str(x['address1']) +' '+ str(x['address2'])

            # delete address2
            y['address2'] = np.nan
    except:
        pass

    return y


df.apply(f, axis=1)

Out[213]:
           address1  address2
0    15 Main Street  New York
1    10 High Street        LA
2    5 Other Street    London
3               NaN     Tokyo
4   15 Grove Street       NaN
5  12 Garden Street       NaN
```

**Note**: it is reccommended that `apply` should not modify the passed object, so I do `y = x.copy()` and modify and return `y`

Comment: Thanks. Whyis it recommended that apply should not modify the passed object? Do you have some info I can read up on?

Comment: @SCool: it may sometimes return unpredictable result as in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961451/pandas-groupby-apply-has-different-behaviour-with-int-and-string-types

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mask and update:

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df.address1, errors='coerce').notna()
df.loc[mask, 'address1'] = df.loc[mask, 'address1'] + ' ' +df.loc[mask,'address2']
df.loc[mask, 'address2'] = np.nan
```

output:

```
           address1  address2
0    15 Main Street  New York
1    10 High Street        LA
2    5 Other Street    London
3               NaN     Tokyo
4   15 Grove Street       NaN
5  12 Garden Street       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

apply try except and convert address1 in int

```
def test(row):
    try:
        address = int(row['address1'])
        return 1
    except:
        return 0


df['address1'] = np.where(df['test']==1,df['address1']+ ' '+df['address2'],df['address1'])
df['address2'] = np.where(df['test']==1,np.nan,df['address2'])
df.drop(['test'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
        address1    address2
0   15 Main Street    New York
1   10 High Street    LA
2   5 Other Street    London
3   NaN               Tokyo
4   15 Grove Street   NaN
5   12 Garden Street  NaN
```